# How to Split notepad file line by line using python?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have a text file that contains the following contents. I want to split this file into multiple files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt...)

My txt file is as below:

```
08-21 10:49:35.563 D/Primes  (13162): Package metric disabled.
08-21 10:49:35.563 D/Primes  (13162): Battery metric disabled
08-21 10:49:35.563 D/Primes  (13162): MagicEye logging metric disabled
```

I would like to split like,

1.txt:
08-21 10:49:35.563 D/Primes  (13162): Package metric disabled.

2.txt:
08-21 10:49:35.563 D/Primes  (13162): Battery metric disabled

3.txt:
08-21 10:49:35.563 D/Primes  (13162): MagicEye logging metric disabled

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
count = 1
with open('My.txt') as f:
    for item in f.readlines():
        tmp = open(str(count) + '.txt', 'w')
        tmp.write(item)
        tmp.close()
        count += 1
```

- It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
  objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its
  suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using
  with is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks.
  [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- `readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character
  `(\n)` is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the
  last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This
  makes the return value unambiguous; if `readline()` returns an empty
  string, the end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is
  represented by `\n`, a string containing only a single newline.
  [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)
- `write(string)` writes the contents of string to the file, returning
  the number of characters written. [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)